# Why urea crystallizes in aqua regia?

Tags: reactivity, precipitation

Recently I stripped gold from old cpu's with ferrous chloride after that I rinsed the cpu's and dissolved them in the aqua regia to get the gold inside when all done, I added urea solution to the filtered aqua regia to precipitate gold if there any. But all I did get is a white crystals.

[image: pic2] [image: pic]

Answer (score 3):

Introduced into concentrated nitric acid, urea produced a white precipitate of urea nitrate $\ce{CO(NH)2·HNO3}$, which can be filtrated and dried. But it must be kept dry. It is decomposed by water into urea and nitric acid in the presence of small amount of water. This compound is known to be a dangerous explosive, which is simple to synthesize. It has been used in Afghanistan war by amateurs who did not get chemical laboratories to synthesize usual explosives. It is extremely difficult to detect after explosion because it is destroyed by water.

Comment: @Marice Plus presence of copper and tin and other element. So how to neutralize it, I don't want that in my home.

Comment: The best thing to do is to destroy it by mixing with enough water. I don't know how much. An equal volume of water should be sufficient, as Wikipedia mentions that this urea nitrate is difficult to maintain in a pure state. The smallest amount of water destroys it into urea and HNO3. But apparently the urea nitrate is soluble in water, but it is quickly decomposed when in solution. And the solution contains only nitric acid and urea. Nitric acid can be neutralized by sodium carbonate, or sodium hydrogen carbonate.

Comment: @Tartard It's better to have a look at the MSDS of urea nitrate: https://www.chemblink.com/MSDS/MSDSFiles/124-47-0_Pfaltz-Bauer.pdf